# Does Nlog use MSMQ

Tags: nlog

I have implemented NLog in my MVC project which logs to Db.
There is a suggestion to use NLog queue.
Found some information [here](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/T_NLog_Targets_MessageQueueTarget.htm)

Sample config shows how NLog will handle the number of objects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <targets>
       <!-- Log in a separate thread, possibly queueing up to
       5000 messages. When the queue overflows, discard any
       extra messages-->

       <target name="file" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="5000" overflowAction="Discard">
           <target xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${level}.txt" />
       </target>
   </targets>

   <rules>
       <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

So my question is does NLog use MSMQ by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NLog does not use MSMQ. The queue is in memory and the limit defines the maximum size of the queue, to avoid using up the whole memory.

The overflow action defines what should be done when the queue is full.